# java synchronized how can i understand it

Tags: java, synchronized

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class unsafeList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                synchronized (list) {
                    list.add(Integer.toString(finalI));
                }
            }).start();
        }
//        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println(list.size());
        String string = list.stream()
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum)
                .toString();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

output:
93
5050
output2:
101
5050
I put a synchronization lock on the list to ensure that the ArrayList can add information safely, but the numbers I printed out were not as many as I imagined, and then I performed the accumulation operation and found that the obtained value was the correct result.
if I change `list.size` to `list.stream.count()` method ,that's right result, How should I understand it?

Comment: The threads you started are likely not finished when you try and read from the list

Comment: In addition to the threads not being finished, you also need to synchronize access to the list for the `list.size()` call and the duration of the `list.stream()....toString()` operation, in order to guarantee visibility of the `add`s.

Comment: ^--- And this should be an answer

Comment: You synchronized the list only within a thread execution and that would come into picture only once a thread begins execution and reaches the statement. In your case, as there are several threads, the sync block is not being reached at all for all threads. So what you want is to synchronize the complete operation. In this case, it can be achieved by joining all threads.

Comment: Further, to answer your point about why it works when you use list.stream.count() - It is entirely dependent on the underlying implementation of the collection, i.e. ArrayList in your case. The behavior may differ for another implementation. You need to see Stream, Spliterators etc. to understand further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You start the threads, but you don't wait for them to finish, using [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--)
2. You don't synchronize access to the list from the main thread, with the `size()` and `stream()` calls.

   Note that the [Javadoc for `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says:

   > If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

   It's perhaps easy to forget that the main thread is a thread like any other, and so you need synchronization there too.